# AWS Event Pipe Filter not allowing event in Terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-event-bridge

I have set up a simple event bridge pipe between 2 SQS queues `example-source` and `example-target`. It works fine if I remove the filter in the `source_parameters` section. However once I add in the source_parameters filter the message does not come through to the target. Below is the terraform I used to create stack:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "main" {}

resource "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = {
      Effect = "Allow"
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      Principal = {
        Service = "pipes.amazonaws.com"
      }
      Condition = {
        StringEquals = {
          "aws:SourceAccount" = data.aws_caller_identity.main.account_id
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "source" {
  role = aws_iam_role.example.id
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "sqs:DeleteMessage",
          "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
          "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        ],
        Resource = [
          aws_sqs_queue.source.arn,
        ]
      },
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "source" {
    name = "example-source"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "target" {
  role = aws_iam_role.example.id
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "sqs:SendMessage",
        ],
        Resource = [
          aws_sqs_queue.target.arn,
        ]
      },
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "target" {
    name = "example-target"
}

resource "aws_pipes_pipe" "example" {
  depends_on = [aws_iam_role_policy.source, aws_iam_role_policy.target]
  name       = "example-pipe"
  role_arn   = aws_iam_role.example.arn
  source     = aws_sqs_queue.source.arn
  target     = aws_sqs_queue.target.arn

  source_parameters {
    filter_criteria {
      filter {
        pattern = jsonencode({
          eventSource = ["aws:sqs"]
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tested it with the following command

```
aws sqs send-message --queue-url https://sqs.<region>.amazonaws.com/<account>/example-source  --message-body "Your message here" --region <region>
```

I was expecting the SQS event from `example-source` to come through to `example-target` based on the filter criteria `eventSource = ["aws:sqs"]`. However nothing comes through to the target.

Comment: According to [the user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-event-filtering.html), you can't filter on `eventSource`, so that's probably the problem

Comment: Yes that fixed it. You can filter based on the message body, not the added attributes